# JavaFX 8 2d Scroller

Tags: animation, javafx, path, scroller, translate-animation

Hey I am trying to make a simple 2d scroller but I simply cannot seem to get the picture to scroll. I am using an ImagveView for the picture, and I have tried both a translatetransition and a pathtransition, but I can't get any good results? Here is my code:

```
public void aboutSceneAnimation() {

    Rectangle2D psb = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

    Path path = new Path();
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
    moveTo.setX(0.0);
    path.getElements().add(moveTo);
    PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
    pt.setDuration(Duration.INDEFINITE);
    pt.setNode(map);
    pt.setPath(path);
    pt.setCycleCount(4);
    pt.setAutoReverse(true);

    pt.play();
}

public Scene aboutScene() {
    Rectangle2D psb = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

    //Create the map

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    border.getChildren().addAll(map2);

    //Size the map

    map2.setFitWidth(psb.getWidth());
    map2.setFitHeight(psb.getHeight());

    Scene scene = new Scene(border, 500, 500);
    aboutSceneAnimation();
    return scene;

}
```

The way it works is that when the program starts there is a start scene loaded into my stage, and then I just show the stage. When a button is pressed I simply change to the aboutScene which also calls the aboutSceneAnimation, which is where I want the map to scroll. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Pane instead of a [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html), because in a BorderPane the center node will be resized to fill the available space in the middle.

In your [PathTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html) you only add from where to start, i. e. the [MoveTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/MoveTo.html), but you don't add where it should go, e. g. a [LineTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/LineTo.html).

---

*Additional note:*

*Since your example in the question contains only bits and pieces that don't work together, please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*